# How to Install Ubuntu on Droid Bionic

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

I checked the official supported device list and noticed the Droid Bionic was not listed despite its 1GHz dual core processor and 1GB of RAM. Is there a working setup with a specific ROM that works with it?

Answer (score 1):

Not aware of a specific distribution of Ubuntu suited for Droid. But I understand it can be hacked if one is willing to take the time.

- I do not condone this, but here is the link:

http://www.droidforums.net/forum/hacking-help/97199-how-run-ubuntu-droid.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the recently announced [Ubuntu for Android](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android), it is currently being marketed to device manufacturers rather than as a third party firmware update for existing handsets.

When the source code is released, some people may build alternate firmware images for existing phones containing the software, but those are not available yet.  The level of integration makes it a bit more difficult than just installing an Android app on a phone.

Comment: I am aware of this. On Ubuntu's app description, it says it requires a kernel with loopback support and busybox installed before installation. My phone has been rooted, so I had assumed it would overwrite over whichever ROM I already had on there.

Comment: Which app description are you referring to?